# Which would be an efficient way to work with an array of polynomials?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a function wich given two polynomials, p and q, calculates the integral of p/q between the real numbers a and b. The funcion I have is$\phi$:

```
import numpy as np
def integrate_pdivq(a, b, P, Q, r):
"""
Calculates the definite integral of P(x)/Q(x) between a and b, assuming  gr P<gr Q and that Q have all different roots, all of which have nonzero imaginary part. 
Parameters:
P: list with coefficients of polynomial P.
Q: list with coefficients of polynomial Q.
r: list with the roots of Q. 

"""

Q_deriv = np.polyder(Q)

fracc = ( np.polyval(P, r)/np.polyval(Q_deriv, r) )
inte = ( 0.5 * np.log((b-r.real)**2+(r.imag)**2) + 1j * np.arctan((b-r.real)/(r.imag)) ) - ( 0.5 * np.log((a-r.real)**2+(r.imag)**2) + 1j * np.arctan((a-r.real)/(r.imag)) )    


return np.sum(fracc*inte)
```

I'm sure that this works. Now, I'm having serious troubles for making this function to work with multidimensional parameters. I mean, I want to be able to use as parameters P, Q, r 4 dimensional arrays, so the output would be as well, a 4D array. 
I think the main trouble I have is that I don't find an efficient way to work with arrays of polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I just demonstrated in another question (I think asked by you) how the logic of `polyder` can be applied to a 2d array of coefficients.  Based on a quick glance at the code for `polyval` it should be just as easy to apply that to a 2d array of coefficients.

The core of `polyval' is:

```
for i in range(len(p)):
    y = x * y + p[i]
```

For a nd `p` (i.e. 'rows' of coefficients), do something like:

```
for i in range(p.shape[-1]):
     y = x * y + p[...,i]
```

You might have to adjust dimensions so that `x`,`y` and `p` broadcast nicely.

There's nothing deep or mysterious about the polynomial functions in numpy.  It is just doing simple math with the coefficients and the numeric variables.  They look like convenience functions, not a comprehensive polynomial package.